# Why am I unable to use cor.test() for point-biserial data?

Tags: r, correlation

I'm solving a task in Andy's Discovering Statistics using R. It's about gender and arousal for certain films. The data frame used is called `chickFlick`, and it looks as follows:

```
    gender                 film arousal
1   Male Bridget Jones' Diary      22
2   Male Bridget Jones' Diary      13
3   Male Bridget Jones' Diary      16
4   Male Bridget Jones' Diary      10
5   Male Bridget Jones' Diary      18
6   Male Bridget Jones' Diary      24
```

When I executed this command:

```
> cor.test(chickFlick$gender,chickFlick$arousal)
```

It returned:

```
Error in cor.test.default(chickFlick$gender, chickFlick$arousal) : 
  'x' must be a numeric vector
```

However, I was doing exactly what the answer key says. I could change the gender levels into 0s and 1s, but the textbook doesn't say it's necessary. What went wrong?

Comment: `cor.test` will only work with '*numeric vectors*' as noted in the documentation. You can also see this check in the code for the function at `stats:::cor.test.default` - `if (!is.numeric(x)) 
        stop("'x' must be a numeric vector")`  and `if (!is.numeric(y)) 
        stop("'y' must be a numeric vector")` . As far as I can tell, either the answer key is wrong or the variables used are different.

Comment: Since we don't have `chickFlick` and you did not paste the output of `str(chickFlick)`, we can't tell what the data types are. It is possible that `gender` is a factor in which case `with(chickFlick, cor.test(as.numeric(gender), arousal))` would work.

Comment: Thanks for both of your help.